Unexpected Keybinding Behavior
I would like to bind "Copy" to the keys Command + w (as in emacs).
To effect this, in MenuSetup.tr I have edited the MenuKey for "Copy" and written
MenuItem["&Copy", "Copy", MenuKey["w", Modifiers->{"Command"}]]

After this change, copying only works with Command + W (capital W) as if the MenuKey were actually
MenuItem["&Copy", "Copy", MenuKey["W", Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]]

This anomalous keybinding behavior persists if MenuKey["w", Modifiers->{"Command"}] is bound to other functions (e.g. to "Paste").
This behavior is persistent across Mathematica versions through 14.0.
I have tried using different keyboards and checked the signal sent by the keyboards to ensure the combination cmd + w is actually being sent.

Can anyone reproduce this behavior?
How can I make it so that the lowercase binding is used?


I assume you are actually using a lowercase w in the definition of your keybinding?

Yes, it is a lowercase w

Partial answer / workaround:
The menu bar contains items which may be opened with the key combination Command + X where X is the corresponding letter of the menu item:
̲ile ̲dit ̲nsert Fo̲mat ̲ell ̲raphics E̲aluation ̲alettes ̲indow ̲elp
The desired keybinding, Command + w, is already bound to open the menu item "̲indow".
This can be overridden by

Removing the menu bar, e.g. by evaluating
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements -> {"VerticalScrollBar"}]

in the current notebook.

Adding the new keybinding into MenuSetup.tr:
MenuItem["&Copy", "Copy", MenuKey["w", Modifiers->{"Command"}]]



